AWS Cloudfront S3 for Apple App Site Association NoSuchKey
I'm using my React web app (which is hosted using AWS Cloudfront and S3) to host my apple-app-site-association for my iOS app.
I know that I have it stored on S3 correctly because when I go to https://my-domain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association it displays my file correctly. And, it is set to application/json
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "My.Bundle.ID",
        "paths": [
            "/referral/*",
            "/share/godo/*",
            "/share/dinner/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "My.Bundle.ID"
        ]
    }
}

But, the issue is when I try to go to the path that should be handled by the cloud front distribution I get "NoSuchKey".
https://my-domain/share/dinner/26C36863-061F-4A93-AF4A-8896079A9038 causes the error message below:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>share/dinner/26C36863-061F-4A93-AF4A-8896079A9038</Key>
<RequestId>TSPGMC3E7KPER0R7</RequestId>
<HostId>
qk/KhCsh6Txwkq+RVdPk53edbQbJZslSYsD96eydj8L5hVvn/pCmYjDOh10ZZcfsziBgmvGXh0Q=
</HostId>
</Error>

I suspect it's an issue with the behavior. The image are my cache settings for the /share/* behavior. And, I also have Fuction Association set to the following -
Viewer request - Lambda@Edge - function name - include body (yes)
And, the function is meant to handle the request and send the user to the right location depending on if they have the app downloaded. But I'm not even reaching this function because none of the console logs are appearing.
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    
    console.log("hitting")

    const userAgent = headers['user-agent'] ? headers['user-agent'][0].value : '';

    
        const response = {
        status: '200',
        statusDescription: 'OK',
        headers: {
                    'content-type': [{
                        key: 'Content-Type',
                        value: 'text/html'
                    }],
                },
        body: '<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>',
        };
        return response;
};

I'd really appreciate any insights!! I've been working on this forever :,0
